# ¿por que al desinstalar la app me borra archivos descargados?

Tags: android-studio, download

hola hice una aplicación que se conecta con cloudstore de firebase y descargo un archivo mp3 ( lo guarda en la carpeta download ).

Pero al desinstalar la aplicación me borra también el archivo descargado.
¿por que pasa esto y como evitar que los archivos descargados se borren?

```
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
        request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI|DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
        request.setTitle("nombre de la cancion.mp3");
        request.setDescription("descargando archivo...");
        //request.allowScanningByMediaScanner(); obsoleto
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,"logos - la industria del poder/"+"no te rindas.mp3");
        DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        manager.enqueue(request);
```

Comment: en el caso que ya haya eliminado los archivos descargados habra alguna forma de recuperarlos? los descargue por medio de la aplicacion giraffeplayer y no los renombre, a los pocos dias se borraron aun sin desinstalar la aplicacion, ya instale algunas app para recuperarlas pero ha sido imposible, es como si nunca hubiera estado los videos en el telefono

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si estas usando `DownloadManager` y se elima la informaciòn descargada debes asegurar primeramente que no estes llamando el mètodo `remove()` :

```
downloadManager.remove(downloadId);
```

De otra forma si tus archivos son removidos automàticamente, debes considerar lo siguiente, el servicio `DownloadIdleService` va a eliminar los archivos que descargados que no se hayan actualizado en una semana esto para mantener tu dispositivo limpio de alguna forma:

> Elimina las descargas obsoletas que probablemente se hayan olvidado
> las aplicaciones de terceros. Solo consideramos las descargas no
> visibles que no se han tocado en más de una semana.

Lo que podrìas realizar para evitar que se eliminen en este caso es renombrar los archivos despuès de descargarlos.

Para evitar esto, define como destino para las descargas :

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
```